# Vite + React not recompiling after React code is changed

Tags: vite

I've modified the default vite.config.js somewhat so that:

1. The React source files live under src/react/
2. The output gets bundled into the output location ./dist/OUTPUT/widget/

The config file looks like:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default ({ mode }) => {
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/react', import.meta.url))
      }
    },
    define: {
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      '__APP_VERSION__': JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_version)
    },
    build: {
      /* cssCodeSplit: false, */
      outDir: './dist/OUTPUT/widget',
      rollupOptions: {
        input: {
          main: './src/react/main.jsx'
        },
        output: {
          entryFileNames: `[name].js`,
          chunkFileNames: `[name].js`,
          assetFileNames: `[name].[ext]`
        }
      }
    }
  })
};
```

If I run `vite build`, it recompiles the React code and updates the `dist/OUTPUT/widget/main.js` file correctly.

However I also need to be able to use the HTTP server to test locally. (I have a test.html page that loads the output JS file.) If I run just `vite`, and edit one of the React source files, it does **not** recompile them.

What am I missing to get Vite to recompile React JS while running the Vite server?

Comment: Similar problem - what did you do to fix it?

Comment: This was a while back, but I did get it working, although I think it might have been a matter of restarting browser/deleting node modules and package-lock.json, and reinstalling. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yes, I got it working. I was following a training module from Microsoft that used dev containers. It was very slow and it did not work properly. I moved to my local drive and everything worked fine there.